# Google Fusion Table Query using FusionTablesLayerOptions' query parameter not working

Tags: javascript, sql, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

My goal is to create a google.maps.FusionTablesLayer from the results of a Fusion Table's query. I have a publicly available [Google Fusion Table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1JUAkUL5H7IhU4QrmLuVQ65Tg2SNyI5Xqm3A7Nk1g) which has been "Enabled for Download". I am able to successfully query the table using the Google Fusion Tables REST API as follows (I would provide a link to the API but don't have enough reputation). The below query works in browser:

https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=SELECT+start_lat+,+dir+FROM+1JUAkUL5H7IhU4QrmLuVQ65Tg2SNyI5Xqm3A7Nk1g+WHERE+dir=%27Northbound%27&key=AIzaSyBCjde_rx_Fe0v4G_vD-uI33M1o9toMF2A.

What I really want is to be able to create a Google Fusion Tables Layer Object with the results of the query. It seems the easiest way to do this is by providing the above query as a parameter during initialization of the Google Fusion Tables Layer Object (as shown in the JavaScript FusionTablesLayer API). However, the FusionTablesLayer fails to show up when queried during initialization as follows:

```js
northbound_hikers_start_layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'start_lat',
    from: '1JUAkUL5H7IhU4QrmLuVQ65Tg2SNyI5Xqm3A7Nk1g',
    where: "dir = 'Northbound'"
  },
  heatmap: {
    enabled: true
  },
  suppressInfoWindows: false
});
```

I am having trouble understanding why the 'where' clause is failing when passing the query as a parameter to the FusionTablesLayer object, yet the Fusion Tables REST API query works fine in browser. I have read the API, but the page regarding this particular topic is surprisingly incomplete. Any ideas? I wish I could include more links to the specific API's I am using but my StackOverflow reputation is not high enough to post more than 2 URLs. The end goal is a FusionTablesLayer with only the data obtained by the query.

EDIT: It might be helpful to know that the map displays properly when I delete the 'where' clause (which leads me to believe the query is the issue). I forgot to mention that I do assign the layer a map as follows:

```js
 $("button").click(function() {
   console.log(this.id + " button was pressed.");
   if (this.id == "toggle-at-centerline-button") {
     //Toggle AT Centerline Layer
     if (!toggle_at_centerline_button_pressed) {
       centerline_layer.setMap(map);
       toggle_at_centerline_button_pressed = true;
     } else {
       centerline_layer.setMap(null);
       toggle_at_centerline_button_pressed = false;
     }
   } else if (this.id == "toggle-at-shelter-button") {
     //Toggle AT Shelters Layer
     if (!toggle_at_shelter_button_pressed) {
       shelterLayer.setMap(map);
       toggle_at_shelter_button_pressed = true;
     } else {
       shelterLayer.setMap(null);
       toggle_at_shelter_button_pressed = false;
     } etc...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `map` property of the [FusionTablesLayerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayerOptions) (or at least set it at some point):

```
var northbound_hikers_start_layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'start_lat',
    from: '1JUAkUL5H7IhU4QrmLuVQ65Tg2SNyI5Xqm3A7Nk1g',
    where: "dir = 'Northbound'"
  },
  heatmap: {
    enabled: true
  },
  suppressInfoWindows: false,
  map: map
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x89q3h22/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.232253, -76.640625),
      zoom: 4,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var northbound_hikers_start_layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'start_lat',
      from: '1JUAkUL5H7IhU4QrmLuVQ65Tg2SNyI5Xqm3A7Nk1g',
      where: "dir = 'Northbound'"
    },
    heatmap: {
      enabled: true
    },
    suppressInfoWindows: false,
    map: map
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I do have the map property set at a later point when a display button is pressed. The code I have above works fine when I remove the 'where' clause. Its only with the presence of the 'where' clause that nothing shows up. I will edit the original question to reflect this information.

Comment: Thanks to your "proof of concept fiddle" I discovered the error. The query is working (as your fiddle shows), I was testing the display with 'where:"dir = 'Southbound'"''. My table is too big so the data was not being returned as part of the 100,000 entries accessible to the query. As a result the 'Northbound' query succeeds and the 'Southbound' query appears to fail. I have marked the question as answered because your fiddle shows an example of a working query, leading me to realize my error. I hope other's find this useful; thank you for the working example!

Comment: That is why providing a [mcve] in the question is important.